# Divergence of the sequence $a_n=\frac{1-n^3}{70-4n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it correct to say that

$$a_n=\frac{1-n^3}{70-4n^2}$$

diverges since the numerator increases faster than the numerator? That would mean that it's approaching infinity, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-n^3}{70-4n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1-n^3}{n^2}}{\frac{70-4n^2}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{n^3}{n^2}}{\frac{70}{n^2}-\frac{4n^2}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}-n}{\frac{70}{n^2}-4}=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Right.  For instance,  divide through by $n^3$.  Then we get:  $$\frac{\frac1{n^3}-1}{\frac{70}{n^3}-\frac4n}\to\frac10=\infty$$.

To be a little more rigorous, apply L'Hôpital's rule a couple times:  $$\frac{-6n}{-8}\to\infty$$.